# How to resize the iPhone/iPad Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9, simulator

The iPad-simulator is really small (like one third the size of the real `iPad` screen) on my 23" Full-HD screen (and also on the `15" MacBook Pro`).

Is there a way to resize it?

I know it must maintain size and dpi-ratio to prevent sub-pixels, but I can hardly see anything withoout a magnifier.

Comment: Just drag the corner of the screen to resize, in modern Xcode.  (See answer from @Krunal below.)

Comment: Here is perfect answer: [Adjusting the XCode iPhone simulator scale and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606926/adjusting-the-xcode-iphone-simulator-scale-and-size/44946608#44946608)

Answer (score 318, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for 100%
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for 75%
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for 50%

Comment: zoom options are greyed out...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142132/cant-scale-device-window-in-ios-simulator

Comment: `⌘+4` and `⌘+5` for 33% and 25% respectively. Requires Xcode 6.3.

Comment: Ok cool, now can I return it to its original size? :D

Answer (score 13):

It's more flexible with Xcode 9-Simulator.Just pick & drag any corner of simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

---

**Note: With Xcode 9.1+, Simulator scale options are changed.**

**Keyboard short-keys**:

 According to Xcode 9.1+

```
Physical Size       ⌘ 1      command + 1
Pixel Accurate      ⌘ 2      command + 2
```

According to Xcode 9

```
50% Scale           ⌘ 1      command + 1
100% Scale          ⌘ 2      command + 2
200% Scale          ⌘ 3      command + 3
```

---

**Simulator scale options from Xcode Menu**:

> **Xcode 9.1+:**
>   
>  Menubar  ▶  Window  ▶  "Here, options available change simulator scale" (**Physical Size** & **Pixel Accurate**)

**Pixel Accurate**: Resizes your simulator to actual (Physical) device's pixels, if your mac system display screen size (pixel) supports that much high resolution, else this option will remain disabled.

[image]

> *Xcode 9.0*
>   
> Menubar  ▶  Window  ▶  Scale  ▶  "Here, options available change simulator scale"

[image]

---

**Using Terminal Command**

Follow these steps to scale simulator using terminal commands

1. Close/Quit simulator. (if open)
2. Open `Terminal` app (using Spotlight search, Press `⌘ + SPACE` to open spotlight search)
3. Copy following text and paste it next to terminal cursor.

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.3"`

4. Open 'Simulator' (Run your iOS project using Xcode).

You will find simulator scale update.

---

Answer (score 6):

**Xcode 9.x :**

1. Select `Simulator`
2. Goto `Window` tab
3. Select `Physical Size` option (`cmd + 1`)

[image: Screenshot 1]

Now if this dosen’t make size as per your interest then follow below steps :

1. Select `Simulator`
2. Goto `edge of simulator`. This will **convert your cursor to resize option (Bidirectional arrow).**
3. Now using this resize option you can `change the size as you desire`.

**Xcode 8 or below :**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30588057/1753005

Answer (score 5):

For Xcode 9, Beta 6: Deselect "Show Device Bezels" under Window menu. Then Cmd + 2 should scale to 100% (Window Menu -> Scale -> 100%).

Tested using 15" Macbook Pro (2017 Model).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is no need to turn off bezels. Just drag to resize to whatever size you want. If your screen is just barely too small to fit at 100% then turning off bezels might allow it to fit but that is not a general answer to the overall question.

Comment: Ah, my apologies! I added another situation in case anyone experiences this. Again, I did specify the version of Xcode which for me did not allow other dorma of resizing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

Window > Uncheck Show Device Bezels

After that, you can customize your simulator's width and length.
If you're satisfied in its size, you can check again the 'Show Device Bezels'

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 10 I ended up having to do

```
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator DevicePreferences
```

I just could not find any other way to reset zoom level.  Even using Window->Zoom to toggle zoom, would not restore back to 100% (2042x2732 iPad 12.9-inch).

Deleting device preferences allowed the simulator to open at full resolution again, so I could take the screen shots required for app store submission.

The `Physical Size` and `Pixel Accurate` options remain greyed out.

Comment: They are greyed out because "Show device bezels" is unselected, I guess. Try to select that option.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the old scale system (100%, 75%, etc.) is removed, but under **Window** tab there are four options:

- Physical Size
- Point Accurate
- Pixel Accurate
- Fit Screen
  Which can be toggled with:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

As seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> But in the smaller screens(MacBook Pro 15-Inch), I can't scale it more than the screen size

There are little utilities that allows you to set your display resolution much higher as the System Preference may offer you.

For instance, if u need 12.9-Inch Retina Display screenshot with a resolution of 2048 x 2732 pixels for portrait. I simply use one of these utilities (e.g.: Display Menu from the App Store) to set my Macbook Pro 2017 Retina display to 3360x2100.

After that I start the Xcode Simulator with a 12,9" iPad Retina and resize the Simulator to the maximum of the screen. As a result, I get exactly 2048 x 2732 which is ready to upload to the App Store.

[image]

Hope that is useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 9.x**

You can resize any simulator in the same way of expanding any windows in Mac. Move the mouse over the corner of any simulators and the pointer changes. Click and drag to expand/shrink the simulator. Verified using Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 9.4 this is the only thing which worked:
-Uncheck "Optimize rendering for window size" in the "Debug" menu.
-take a *screen shot using "⌘s" or "New screen shot" from the file maenu.

*note - it doesn't matter what size the simulator is, the screen shot will be the correct size for uploading to iTunes Connect

Answer (score 0):

CMD + Space

Search for **System Preferences**

Then Select **Accessibility**

Choose **Zoom**

**Check** Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:

Select CMD Key or Option (whichever you prefer)

Thats it:

Now on your trackpad do 
**CMD + 2 finger UP and Down** to Scroll to **Zoom in** or **Zoom out**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Look at this picture.
2. See the red tips.
3. You can resize your ios simulator easy.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer so the explanation is in text, in the answer itself. That will make it more accessible to future readers. It is best if images simply **support** answers.