# Regarding IOS simulator

Tags: ios-simulator

I know some people might not found this question useful.

Below lines are picked up from apple website.
iOS Simulator provides the ability to simulate six devices:

1. iPhone
2. iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)
3. iPhone Retina (4-inch)
4. iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)
5. iPad
6. iPad Retina

But when I installed Xcode 5, I didn't get "iPhone" simulator instead I have iPad Retina 64 bit

**So how to get iPhone simulator?** ...because if I use other simulator they are so big they take up entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone simulator is the non-retina iPhone, and it doesn't support iOS7.

To get iPhone available in your list, you have to set your deployment target to iOS6.1 or prior.

Comment: Everyone is facing the same problem right.I thought there was some glitch when installing Xcode.

Comment: oh again am thinking like rookie.

Comment: hey is there any way to get home button on the simulator.I know the shortcut cmd+shift+H but need actually button.

Comment: The only way to simulate the Home button is to use the shortcut or through the hardware menu->Home.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize your simulator than see the link below:

[How to resize the iPhone/iPad Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140051/how-to-resize-the-iphone-ipad-simulator)

Comment: Everyone is facing the same problem right.I thought there was some glitch when installing Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution to your both problems, how to resize simulator according to your requirement and how to add (find) new simulator.

**How to resize your simulator?**

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9- Simulator. You can pick & drag any corner of simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot.

[image]

**How to add (find) new simulator?**

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version (iOS 11) from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]