# IPhone 6 plus simulator scaling

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9, simulator

Even after scaling the IPhone 6 plus simulator to 50% (No option to scale less than this), the size is still big to work with it.
How can i scale down it to 25% or less ?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run this in a terminal:

> defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.4"

You may vary "0.4" to your liking. Then, in simulator, hardware-> devices-> iphone 6 plus.

Answer (score 0):

> You can scale iOS simulator to desire scale (I tried from .2 to 1.4 ) and it worked for me.
>
> To do this you have to go to /Library/Preferences and edit com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist >file. Edit value for KEY SimulatorWindowLastScale to desire scale.
>
> I tried this on latest Version of Mountain Lion (10.8.4) and on the iOS 6.0 simulator.

(https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62757/how-do-i-resize-the-ios-simulator)

I tested it on 10.8.x (with other Simulator Devices), but not on 10.9.x or 10.10

Comment: I tried this before but com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist not present.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can *scale down to 25%* of actual resolution in *Xcode 6.3.1*

1. Run you app on Simulator
2. Select **Window -> Scale** (choose percent to be scaled)

*Shortcut keys* :

```
Command Key + 1 : 100%
Command Key + 2 : 75%
Command Key + 3 : 50%
Command Key + 4 : 33%
Command Key + 5 : 25%
```

[image: Screenshot for above steps]