# Take Screen shot from Simulator iPhone in iOS 11 (with 100% scale)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

In `iOS 10` and below when I use `window + s` key then screen shot has been taken from simulator and it has been saved on Desktop but When I used same key in iOS 11 its not working.Please suggest how I will scale and take screen shot in `iOS 11` by shortcut key.

Also, I want 100% scale screen shot that would be uploaded on App Store. But scaling percentage is not showing.

Comment: For iOS 11 simulator also same key combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd>  to capture a screen shot.

Use  <kbd>window + S</kbd> , if you are using windows/non-apple keyboard).

[image]

Here is result (Captured screen shot using short-key :  <kbd>window + S</kbd> )

[image]

See for more details: [How you can change simulator scale options with Xcode 9+.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140051/how-to-resize-the-iphone-ipad-simulator)

**Tip: How do you get screen shot with 100% (a scale with actual device size) that can be uploaded on AppStore?**

Disable 'Optimize Rendering for Window scale' from `Debug` menu, before you take a screen shot (using  <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd>  or Menubar  ▶  File  ▶  New Screen Shot)

There is an option

> Menubar  ▶  Debug  ▶  Disable "Optimize Rendering for Window scale"

[image]

**Tip 2: Where is screen shot saved (Default Path)? How to change default path?**

Simulator saves screen shot file on (logged-in user's) desktop and it's default path.

To change default path (with Xcode 9+), press and hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> (alt) button from keyboard, while you take a screen shot or use keys <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>   + <kbd>⌘</kbd>   + <kbd>s</kbd> all together. It will show to a dialog with file storage options and also allows to set/change default path.

[image]

Comment: I want 100% scale screen shot that would be uploaded on App Store. But scaling percentage is not showing.

Comment: Check window->Scale is enable in Xcode 8.3.2 but when I am checking in Xcode 9.1 and iOS 11 simulator window->scale is disable

Comment: Yes, Xcode 9 simulators has complete different options for scale that you can see in above link.

Answer (score 1):

Same key `command + s` is used to take screenshot in iOS 11 Simulator. Otherwise in simulator goto `File -> New Screen Shot` and take screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Their was some issue from Apple side, When we take screenshot in Xcode 8 version.

They resolved the issue in Xcode 9 Version.

Please let us know which xcode version you are using.