# iOS Simulator No Scale options and No Windowbar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, scale, simulator

My iOS Simulator on the Mac has a little problem. Its set to big size (i think 100%, but I'm not sure) And i cant resize it, because the scale options are greyed out. Also there is no Window-Bar shown, where i could minimize or close the iOS Simulator, but on the other Mac I have the Window-Bar is shown, as well as the Size Options aren't greyed out.

The Scales of the Displays are the Same (1920x1080).

Thanks, Loki

Comment: Check Window->Scale options. Or command+1, command+2, command+3

Comment: I already said this doesn't work. All options are greyed out and the shortcuts don't work.

Comment: I've run into the same problem if the size of the simulator is large than my screen size. Like for example if I run the simulator in iPad retina mode there is no window border. Try changing the simulator to iPhone non retina mode.

Comment: The Scale Options are greyed out and the Windowbar is hided, no matter what device is selected (ipad,iphone,iphone retina). Every device the same happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142132/cant-scale-device-window-in-ios-simulator

take a look at this question