# Actual size disable in XCode 9 iPhone simulator scale

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

I am not able to change my simulator size in XCode9.It is disable default. How can i change it? Please check screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Drag any corner of simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.  Look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45349424/5039344